# jquery jscrollpane hijackInternalLinks with 2 srollables

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

The HiJackInternalLinks work only with one srollable div per page correct. When i use 2 scrollable divs the scrollbars are going away they scroll with when hit the mousewheel it jumps back to beginn. You can see it live here http://testserver.ihrcms.de/flammenmehr/vita.php?id=68 used code below for more look sourcecode from link, thanks for looking!

```
$(function() {

    // initialize scrollable
    $(".scrollable").scrollable();

});

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var resize_handler = function(){
                $('.item').css('width', String(parseInt($('body').width()))+'px');
            };
            $(window).resize(resize_handler);
            resize_handler();
        });

$(function()
{
    $('#left').jScrollPane({
            showArrows: true,
            hideFocus: true,
            horizontalGutter: 30,
            verticalGutter: 30,
            verticalDragMinHeight: 66,
            verticalDragMaxHeight: 66,
            horizontalDragMinWidth: 50,
            horizontalDragMaxWidth: 50,
            hijackInternalLinks: true,
            mouseWheelSpeed: 5,
            arrowButtonSpeed: 5 });
});

$(function()
{
    $('#right').jScrollPane({
            showArrows: true,
            hideFocus: true,
            horizontalGutter: 30,
            verticalGutter: 30,
            verticalDragMinHeight: 66,
            verticalDragMaxHeight: 66,
            horizontalDragMinWidth: 50,
            horizontalDragMaxWidth: 50,
            hijackInternalLinks: true,
            mouseWheelSpeed: 5,
            arrowButtonSpeed: 5 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with the current release of jScrollPane:
https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues#issue/25

Please watch that ticket to find out when there is a solution...